# Model Deployment: export Scikit Learn Pipeline or Model only?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, model

Following ML best practices, I use Scikit Pipelines to make sure my data preprocessing is the same at each model development iteration.

Also as a best practice, once I have completed model development I retrain the best model with the chosen hyperparameters on the entire dataset.

Now, in order to prepare for a deployment to production, I am trying to understand if I should export the model chosen itself, or the entire Pipeline object? I would want to apply the same exact preprocessing steps in production, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to export the model which includes the list of transformers defined by the pipeline and the final estimator.

To give a simple example:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('linreg', LinearRegression())])
pipe.fit(X, y)
```

Now you can save your model for example via pickle for use in production:

```
import pickle
s = pickle.dumps(pipe)
```